# kafka offset and lag is unknown for some partitions of a topic

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

[image]

I am using consumer from https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go. The kafka version is 0.10.1.0.

Here is the configuration of my consumer:

```
kafkaClient, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
    "bootstrap.servers":               broker,
    "group.id":                       "udwg20",
    "session.timeout.ms":              60000,
    "go.events.channel.enable":        true,
    "go.application.rebalance.enable": true,
    "default.topic.config": kafka.ConfigMap{
        "auto.offset.reset":      "earliest",
        "enable.auto.commit":      true,
        "auto.commit.interval.ms": 10000}})
```

At the beginning, all current-offset and lag was showed, but after running several hours, the offset and lag of some partitions (which are not received any new message) become unknown. If there is a message come to a partition which its offset and lag are unknown, the offset and lag will be visible again, and the message will be consumed.

When there are some partitions with unknown current-offset and lag, I restart the consumer, at this time, all current partitions with unknown current-offset and lag status will be consumed again from beginning, but other partitions seem to run normally.

I also used a python consumer that consumes message from this topic with a different consumer group id. the python consumer seem to work well without any partition which has unknown current-offset and lag.

Answer (score 1):

`offsets.retention.minutes` is used for clean up inactive consumer groups. If a consumer group does not commit any offset for `offsets.retention.minutes` (defaults to 24h), kafka will clean up its offset. This is why offset and log are set to `unknown`.

You can increase offset retention period however, be aware that old consumers will reserve space in `__consumer_offsets` topic.

Comment: I have set offsets.retention.minutes=10080 (7 days) in the configuration, and restart kafka, but after running about 3 to 5 hours, the current-offset and lag still change to unknown. I don't think that my consumer group is inactive, because the current-offset and lag were showed for some partitions, it proves my consumer group is active

Comment: @hongnguyenhuu96 an you confirm that the offset topic is using compaction and the broker is set to enable compaction?

Comment: yes. In the server.properties.

    `log.cleanup.policy=compact`
    `offsets.retention.minutes=10080`

I also used a python consumer that does the same function (I want to convert code of this python consumer to golang for better performance). There are no partition with unknown offset and lag for python consumer. I think the problem is about the library. 
Now, I am trying to using poll api instead of using go chanel event.

Comment: I have tried to use consumer.poll api, but after 2 hours, it still happens. The current-offset  and lag now is unknown for some partitions.

Comment: @hongnguyenhuu96 Does this happen with your Python consumer too?

Comment: No, for python consumer, current-offset and lag of all partitions are clear.

Comment: go consumer: [image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12449250/46344253-c0e70a00-c66a-11e8-9b4c-542021cfbe8c.png)

python consumer: [image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12449250/46344271-cf352600-c66a-11e8-9a23-4a66863cb89f.png)

Answer (score 0):

I use the command bellow to see whether the offset of my consumer group id is commited periodically or not.

```
echo exclude.internal.topics=false > consumer.properties

kafka-console-consumer --consumer.config consumer.properties --from-beginning --topic __consumer_offsets --zookeeper localhost:2181 --formatter "kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter"
```

Although I set the value of `enable.auto.commit` to `true`, it does not commit periodically for partitions which its `lag = 0`. The current offset for those partitions is removed after 2 to 3 hours even the consumer group is still active.

To solve this issue, I set `enable.auto.commit` to `false` and write my own function to commit offset after every 5 seconds.

Here is the ideal:
When a consumer get a new `Message` event or reach end of partition (`PartitionEOF`) event, from the data of the event, I keep the latest current offset in a commit map (key:`topic_partition` value:
`kafka.TopicPartition{ Topic, Partition, Offset }`) and there is a function to commit this map periodically (may be after every 5 seconds). When the consumer get `RevokedPartitions` event, I remove the corresponding key `topic_partition` from the commit map.